# Partial sum of reciprocals of square roots of k-almost primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, divergent-series

Is there a general formula for partial sum of reciprocals of square roots of k-almost primes?

[This gives density of k-almost primes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes?rq=1) as
$$\pi_k(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log{x}} \cdot \frac{({\log{\log{x}})^{k-1}}}{(k-1)!} $$

After a following the method - as suggested - in [a related question about primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287231/partial-sum-square-root-of-reciprocal-of-primes), I am now stuck at evaluating the integral expression in RHS.

Denoting $P_k$ as set of k-almost primes, $p_k$ as a member of set $P_k$, and $\rho_{\kappa}$ is the smallest member of $P_k$, we get:

$$\sum_{\rho_{\kappa}}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{p_k}} = \int_{\rho_{\kappa}}^x \frac{d(\pi_k(t))}{\sqrt{t}} $$
$$ =\frac{\pi_k(t)}{\sqrt{t}} \Big \vert_{\rho_k}^x - \int_{\rho_{\kappa}}^x \pi_k(t) \frac{1}{-2\sqrt{t}} dt $$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log{x}} \cdot \frac{({\log{\log{x}})^{k-1}}}{(k-1)!}
- \frac{\sqrt{\rho_k}}{ \log{\rho_k}} \cdot \frac{({\log{\log{\rho_k}})^{k-1}}}{(k-1)!} \\
+ \frac{1}{2} \int_{\rho_{\kappa}}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t} \log{t}} \cdot \frac{({\log{\log{t}})^{k-1}}}{(k-1)!}dt $$

I am unsure about whether the following integral is convergent - and if it is - it would be nice to find out what it converges to:

$$ \int_{\rho_{\kappa}}^x \frac{({\log{\log{t}})^{k-1}}}{\sqrt{t} \log{t}} \cdot  dt $$

Comment: Do a partial summation.

Comment: You've got "reciprocals of square roots" in your title, and merely "reciprocals" in your question. And, btw, you forgot to mention why anybody would want to consider that. But since you've got the density, partial summation is a very good advice, indeed.

Comment: @reuns, I attempted it. Does that look correct?

Comment: $$\int_a^x \frac{({\log{\log{t}})^{k-1}}}{\sqrt{t} \log{t}} dt \sim x^{1/2}\frac{(\log\log x)^k}{k!}$$